# A DB Instance in a VPC Accessed by an EC2 Instance in a Different VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, rds

I'm confronting with a problem in my enviroment.
I have two VPCs (A - B): - An ec2 instance is based on the first one (VPC A).
- A RDS is based on the second one (VPC B).

And I have two questions :

- How can I access to my RDS by EC2 base in a different VPC ?
- I found two ways but, what is the differences between a Transit Gateway and VPC Peering and what is the best way ?

Thank you per advance

Best

Comment: transit gateway is a separate service whereas VPC peering is just a function of the VPC/EC2 service; they both have costs associated but VPC peering is almost certainly cheaper

Comment: Thank you for your response ! 
So the VPC Peering is cheaper, but I can use it for what I want todo ?

Comment: If you only need to connect two VPCs, VPC Peering is the method to use.

Comment: I would like from my EC2 Instance based on the VPC A to access to the RDS based on the VPC B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- VPC peering is the best choice if you have small infra.
- Both are used to establish connectivity between multiple VPC's but the main difference is Transit Gateway can establish connectivity
  between multiple VPC's and with multiple on-premise Datacenter's. The other disadvantage with VPC peering is that when we have number VPC's we need to do VPC peering with each and every VPC which becomes a mesh. But with Transit Gateway, we can just create one Transit Gateway and connect many VPC's and on-premise Datacenter. Here is the detailed architecture digram that explains better.

[image]

For more detailed steps, I would suggest you watch this [re:invent video](https://aws.amazon.com/transit-gateway/)